# java custom classloader: some classes are not loaded by my classloader

Tags: java, classloader

i'm writing a custom classloader, i'have set it to be the default classloader by using the parameter

```
-Djava.system.class.loader=MyClassLoader
```

Most of the classes are loaded by my classloader, but some classes not, why?
This classes are into an external jar file.

**UPDATE**
Here an example

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            // A simple class loader, ovveride loadClass
            // method and print in stdout the name of the class loaded.
            MyClassLoader classLoader=new MyClassLoader(MyClassLoader.class.getClassLoader());
            Class init=classLoader.loadClass("Initializer");
            Object instance=init.newInstance();
            init.getMethod("init").invoke(instance);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class A{

    public A() {
        System.out.println("Im A");
    }
}

public class Initializer {

     public void init() {
        A a=new A();
    }
}
```

The problem is: I expect that class A are loaded by my class loader, but this is does not happen, why?

**UPDATE**

Anyway, i want to load ALL my classes with my class loader, becouse i want to encrypt class code and decrypt it at runtime.
So, how can i use my class loader as default class loader for ALL my classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Which classes are not loaded by your CL?

Comment: My crystal sphere gleams as if ClassNotFoundException has occurred in this particular case, whereas my java woodoo doll refuses to continue without stacktrace :)

Comment: Your crystal sphere is broken i think, i have no exception, all works, but i notice that some classes are not loaded by my class loader. (i print in stdout when load a class)

Comment: side note: If you're going to decrypt at runtime then ALL of the information needed to decrypt will be available to the host/client machine. This will not make your app secure. Just harder than normal to break into. Is it worth it? Or is it a customeer requirement?

Comment: Yes is into client machine, it works as license key. With a custom decryption algorithm and hiding the key in the machine i achieve a considerable security level. And i need only to obfuscate and protect only one class, the class loader. This is defenitely more easy and strong to obfsucate all classes of my project.

Comment: The JVM will load dependency classes using the class loader of the dependent class.  Show the source for MyClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

Anything under `java.lang` will always be loaded by the bootstrap classloader.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader :

> When the JVM is started, three class
>   loaders are used[3][4]:
>
> 1. Bootstrap class loader
> 2. Extensions class loader
> 3. System class loader
>
> The bootstrap class loader loads the
>   core Java libraries[5]
>   (/lib directory). This
>   class loader, which is part of the
>   core JVM, is written in native code.
>
> The extensions class loader loads the
>   code in the extensions directories
>   (/lib/ext or any other
>   directory specified by the
>   java.ext.dirs system property). It is
>   implemented by the
>   sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader
>   class.

Comment: Is a my class of my external jar. This jar is a my class libraries.

Comment: @blow, I don't understand the first sentence of your question.

Comment: @blow, "Is a my class of my external jar" starts with "Is" so I assumed it was a question.

Comment: Samule: ah, sorry. No is not a question sorry. Anyway, i noticed that with my example in my first post, only Initializer are loaded through my class loader, class A is load by default class loader(i think). In some tutorial i read that sub classes( A in this case) are loaded with the same class loader of the parent( Initializer in this case), so why this does not work?